# sails js waterline exec function access outside variable

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a for loop for around 5000 items to create documents inside MongoDB. 
my code looks like below. Question is how can i access a variable called **rawInfo** inside exec function

```
 for (var i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {

        var rawInfo  = output[i];

     Vehicle.create({make :  rawInfo.make,model: rawInfo.model,year:rawInfo.year,
     tests : {deviceGeneration: rawInfo.deviceGeneration,
        overAllComp:rawInfo.overAllComp}}).exec(function(err,vehCreated){

          if(err && err.originalError && err.originalError.code===50)
           {
              // error vehicle is already present try to add test
              // using ***rawInfo*** variable 
             //VehicleTest.create()     

            }




        });


      }
```

Comment: Please, format and indent the code so we can correctly read it

Comment: what do you mean access it. Can you be more specific about what your trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for my bad format. I think its now better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vehicle_TestInfo` is available in the entire scope of the loop, so you can access it in the inner `exec()` just like you did in the outer `exec()`. If you're going to add more code before calling the inner `exec()` or you wish to avoid calling `vehicle_TestInfo` from the loop-level scope, you might as well retrieve the attributes from `vehCreated` since you have access to that newly created object.

So, either of these will work fine:

```
for (var i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {
    var vehicle_TestInfo  = output[i];

    Vehicle.create({ make : vehicle_TestInfo.make,
                    model: vehicle_TestInfo.model,
                    year: vehicle_TestInfo.year,
                    tests : { deviceGeneration: vehicle_TestInfo.deviceGeneration,
                                overAllComp: vehicle_TestInfo.overAllComp }
            }).exec(function(err,vehCreated){
                if (err && err.originalError && err.originalError.code === 50) {
                    VehicleTest.create({ deviceGeneration: vehicle_TestInfo.deviceGeneration,
                                            overAllComp: vehicle_TestInfo.overAllComp})
                            .exec(function(err,testCreated) {
                                    // more code
                            });
                }
    });
}
```

OR

```
for (var i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {
    var vehicle_TestInfo  = output[i];

    Vehicle.create({ make : vehicle_TestInfo.make,
                    model: vehicle_TestInfo.model,
                    year: vehicle_TestInfo.year,
                    tests : { deviceGeneration: vehicle_TestInfo.deviceGeneration,
                                overAllComp: vehicle_TestInfo.overAllComp }
            }).exec(function(err,vehCreated){
                if (err && err.originalError && err.originalError.code === 50) {
                    VehicleTest.create({ deviceGeneration: vehCreated.deviceGeneration,
                                            overAllComp: vehCreated.overAllComp})
                            .exec(function(err,testCreated) {
                                    // more code
                            });
                }
    });
}
```

PS: As pointed out in the comments, please format your code and frame your question properly. Additionally, try naming your variables with some uniformity. Underscores mixed with camelCase make people feel dizzy.